# SSH session looks hung occasionally, most of the times when opening vi or nano

Tags: ssh, vi, freeze

I am running Windows 10 and using putty or powershell or the built in Ubuntu(WSL) for SSH session to remote ubuntu machines and occasionally the ssh session looks hung...
This happens most of the time when I try to open a file with vi or nano and the result is that I can't see the content of the file or I can see only the first 1-2 lines and nothing works in the terminal anymore. The only option is to close it and start over but it takes multiple retries until I can actually open the file.
Same thing happens sometimes with ls - it prints the partial output and then hangs the same time.

I don't have an idea if the problem is in my client pc - it is relatively new (3 months) and I didn't have this issue with my old pc with the same tools for ssh and remote servers.

Do you have any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an MTU/fragmentation problem. The following may help:
http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html

If you have a router in between I would first check the router settings. Maybe your router is dropping ICMP messages which leads to the problem. For more details see here:
https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Tools_and_Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting_MTU_Issues

Comment: I did test by pinging both hosts to find the maximum packet size it in both direction it is 16600. The MTU settings on the net interfaces for both server and client is actually 1500.
It is actually my home network, so I do have router and the MTU there is also 1500. It has also NAT enabled. But it is a home router TP Link Archer C9 so it doesn't have a lot of configuration options.

I will try to lower the MTU and see what's going to change..

Comment: I got the same issue today and tried more troubleshooting like lowering the MTU to 576 using `ifconfig eth0 mtu 576` as suggested on the first article but this didn't help. Actually I lost notworking on my ubuntu server and had to reboot it to fix (after reverting the mtu to 1500). About the other article, my router doesn't have such options and I don't have access to the remote router.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: but the issue should be on the network... I just verified it is now present for all ssh connections (different servers) to this network